# dayJs - TypeError: date.isBefore is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, dayjs

I am doing this following code for a project where I am getting date in "YYYY-MM-DD" format and passing that into the defaultValue. But getting the above error for which I can't find a solution.

```
<Controller
                value={passengerSelected?.Date_of_Birth}
                name="Date_of_Birth"
                control={control}
                // rules={{required: true}}
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                    <DatePicker
                      label="Date of Birth"
                      sx={{
                        width: {
                          lg: "46%",
                          md: "46%",
                          sm: "100%",
                          xs: "100%",
                        },
                        mt: {
                          lg: "-0.7rem",
                          md: "-0.7rem",
                        },
                      }}
                      // defaultValue={passengerSelected?.Date_of_Birth}
                      onChange={(newValue) => {
                        if (newValue) {
                          field.onChange(dayjs(newValue).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
                        }
                      }}
                      {...field}
                      renderInput={(params) => (
                        <TextField
                          id="date_of_birth"
                          variant="outlined"
                          type="date"
                          sx={{
                            "& .MuiInputBase-input": {
                              // height: "2.3rem !important",
                              padding: "14px 14px",
                              "::placeholder": "Date of Birth",
                            },
                            width: "100%",
                          }}
                          {...params}
                          // error={errors["Due_Date"]}
                        />
                      )}
                    />
                  </LocalizationProvider>
                )}
              />
```

I am expecting it to get the input value and respond to any change that I can catch from react hook form. The issue is that, I am not even using isBefore method anywhere in my code here. But I don't know somehow the error has appeared. The error call stack:

[Error call stack image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejo3l.png)

Please feel free to share your ideas.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75913102/mui-datepicker-not-working-with-formik-date-isbefore-is-not-a-function I solved by this.