# TypeError: date.isBefore is not a function (MUI Datepicker + React Hook Form)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm trying to use the MUI DatePicker with RHF and I'm getting this error when I try to display a date that I receive from a database in ISO format.

This is the custom one:

```
export default function DatePickerStyled({sx, label, control, name, errors, inputFormat, format, views}) {
  return (
    <FormControl>
      <Controller
        name={name}
        defaultValue={new Date()}
        control={control}
        render={({field}) => (
          <DatePickerStyledCustom
            inputFormat={inputFormat}
            format={format}
            views={views}
            sx={sx}
            {...field}
            {...addErrorIntoField(errors[name])}
            label={label}
            />
        )}
      />

      {errors[name] ? <ErrorMessage message={errors[name].message} /> : null}
    </FormControl>
  );
}
```

And this is the implementation:

```
   <DatePickerStyled
      errors={errors}
      control={control}
      name="dateBirth"
      label="Date Input"
      inputFormat="YYYY-DD-MM"
                     
   />
```

The localization provider is wrapping everything in main.jsx:

```
  <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
    <App />
  </LocalizationProvider>
```

I am almost certain it is a date format issue and I have tried changing the format in many different ways:

date.toISOstring(), date.toISOString().substring(0, 10, but I keep getting the same error message.

The date I'm supposed to display comes in the format "2023-05-24".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MUI DatePicker not working with Formik (date.isBefore is not a function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75913102/mui-datepicker-not-working-with-formik-date-isbefore-is-not-a-function)